# Boot black screen after last update

Tags: release-freya, graphic-drivers, boot

After installing latest updates (I think nvidia drivers were updated as well) I can't boot anymore. I get a black screen no matter what I try: adding nomodeset to boot options, choosing recovery mode or a different kernel.

Laptop description:
[Macbook pro 5,3](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-2-duo-2.66-aluminum-15-mid-2009-sd-unibody-specs.html)

Comment: jftr: I can't use any kind of shortcut to open up a tty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to login in console and I installed again all the latest updates.
Everything is fine now, back to normal. :)

Comment: How did you do that?

Comment: Curl + Alt + f1-f6 will spawn a try

Comment: My keyboard is not active here. The screen is black and the keyboard hasn't even started. Did that command give you a terminal?